# KubeView fails to start. How can I start KubeView container and not have it exit right away?

Tags: kubernetes, visualizer

Based on the [**KubeView** README](https://github.com/benc-uk/kubeview), I tried to run **KubeView** using the container provided [here](https://github.com/users/benc-uk/packages/container/package/kubeview).

I run:

```
$ docker run --publish-all --name kubeview ghcr.io/benc-uk/kubeview:0.1.31
```

I get the following output:

```
2023/03/12 18:06:45 ### Kubeview v0.1.31 starting...
2023/03/12 18:06:45 ### Connecting to Kubernetes...
2023/03/12 18:06:45 ### Creating client with config file: /.kube/config
panic: stat /.kube/config: no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /build/cmd/server/main.go:60 +0x6a5
```

I can see that the problem is that the tool is looking for the kubeconfig file in `/.kube/config`. It can't find it because mine is in my home directory, `~/.kube/config/`

I tried to pass an environment variable like this:

```
$ docker run --publish-all --name kubeview -e KUBECONFIG=/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/.kube/config ghcr.io/benc-uk/kubeview:latest
```

It didn't work. Has anyone been able to run `KubeView` as a container? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: @HarshManvar see my comment on your answer. I passed the initial error but getting a new one. Investigating...

Answer (score 1):

You can **mount** your local **kubeconfig** file to the **Docker** image that you are trying, not sure if the way you follow **Env variable** option is suggested anywhere or not

Try something like :

```
docker run --publish-all --name kubeview -v ./config:/.kube/config ghcr.io/benc-uk/kubeview:0.1.31
```

**./config** - will the path of your `~/.kube/config/` **local system**

**/.kube/config** - path where your local file will get set in the container, so when container will run your local file will be available at that path

Tried with **fake** values, which not able to parse but it got the file

```
2023/03/12 19:28:04 ### Kubeview v0.0.0 starting...
2023/03/12 19:28:04 ### Connecting to Kubernetes...
2023/03/12 19:28:04 ### Creating client with config file: /.kube/config
panic: error loading config file "/.kube/config": couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string "json:\"apiVersion,omitempty\""; Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" }

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /build/cmd/server/main.go:60 +0x6a5
```

Comment: Now getting a new error:

    panic: invalid configuration: [unable to read client-cert 
    /Users/<>/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt for minikube due to 
    open /Users/<>/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt: no such file or 
    directory, unable to read client-key 
    /Users/<>/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key for minikube due to 
    open /Users/<>/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key: no such file or 
    directory, unable to read certificate-authority 
    /Users/<>/.minikube/ca.crt for minikube due to open 
    /Users/<>/.minikube/ca.crt:...

Comment: looks like it's looking for other files, cert for auth, and not sure from where it;s taking minikube config